# How to skip custom action in installer during uninstall the patch?

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, patch, custom-action

I have an old MSI installer (based on WIX) and want to build the un-installable patch for it. Unfortunately the installer has not been developed very good. It has custom action (CaSrvCustomAction):

1. Developed in C#
2. It has  condition and is not run in un-install the MSI.
3. It does not have  condition to skip in un-install the patch.
4. It uses some DLLs and patch has to update these DLLs. Some of these DLLs are in GAC and have policy files.
5. Custom action does not have any associated property.

   `<Custom Action='CaSrvCustomAction' After='CaStepCustomAction'> <![CDATA[ NOT REMOVE ]]> </Custom>`

   `<CustomAction Id="CaSrvCustomAction" DllEntry="CaSrvCustomAction"  BinaryKey="CustomActions" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no"  Return="check" />`

Is there any solution to develop the patch to jump over this custom action? Appreciation your idea.

Thanks

Comment: During Uninstall process, the OLD (wrong) msi-installer, will be executed. Not your new one. I think you cannot change an distributed installer. This behaviour should be valid for PATCH or UPDATE or fresh INSTALL.

Comment: A minor upgrade will upgrade the cached installed MSI in-place and not trigger any uninstall. Hence you should be able to "hotfix" the existing installation before any uninstall problems are triggered if you do this correctly. Patching is however very difficult with MSI and error prone. The [PATCH property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/patch) is set during patching and can hence be used for conditioning. Also [search for "patch" on this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/property-reference) to find other properties involved (several).

Comment: Thanks guys for you answers.